# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$ a Galois extension?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Consider the field extension

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$$

> Is it Galois?

I can't quite find the order of the automorphism group.

Comment: *Hint:* Does $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$ contain $\sqrt[3]{2}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Since the goal of SE is to form a repository for good questions and answers, it would be helpful if you could make your question more accessible by including the things one needs to show to prove that the field extension is Galois. Could you do that?

Comment: I agree that question in itself is quite valid and I agree no more explanation is needed. However this shows no working so we do not know how much you know about the theory nor what you have tried. For instance do you know that an extension being galois is same as it being separable and normal?

Comment: @Piekar That might be so, but the point of SE is that questions are not only accessible for people that might contribute to solving it, but also for other people having similar problems, which might benefit from reading your question and its answers.

Comment: @lhf: I don't quite see where you are heading with your hint. We have
$(i\root3\of2)^3=-2i$ in that extension, and consequently also $\root3\of2$ is in there. But how does that help here? Where you perhaps hinting at the need to find the third primitive roots of unity in there?

Comment: @Piekar, what is the minimal polynomial of $i\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? How about over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you're quite right. My mistake.

Comment: @Álvaro Lozano-Robledo, The minimal polynomial for $i\sqrt[3]{2}$ seems to have distinct roots, so I don't get the hint...

Comment: Do you know the relationship between Galois extensions and splitting fields?

Comment: @Álvaro Lozano-Robledo, Ah I see, so it is a Galois extension? I tried to prove it is not.

Comment: I am not saying it is or it isn't Galois. I am just saying that you can prove or disprove it using the connection with splitting fields.

Comment: @lhf, are you saying it is not Galois? I appreciate the game you're playing with me but I'd also appreciate more hints.

Comment: I advise answering @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo’s question explicitly. I found the equation, and could see something very important just by looking at it.

Comment: We keep playing.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566031/compute-the-following-galois-group-g-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt32-i/566941#566941

Answer (score 0):

The comments that have been made seem to contain all that is needed to solve the problem: let me call $c$ the real cubic root of 2 and $K = Q(\sqrt{2})$, to ease notation. Since the element $i c$ is a root of $P(x)= x^6+4 = 0$, a polynomial with coefficients in $K$, the degree of the extension must divide $6$. On the other hand, as noted by Jyrki, $c$ is in the extension, so the degree must be a multiple of 3. If the degree were 3, then $K(c) = K(ic)$, because we have shown that the first is contained in the second and they have both the same degree. But this is a contradiction, because $K(c)$ is a real field, and $ic$ is not real. Thus the degree is $6$, and $P(x)$ is a minimal polynomial for $ic$ over $K$. From here we can conclude that the extension is NOT Galois, by showing that some root of this polynomial, or more generally some "algebraic combination of roots with coefficients in $K$" (i.e., some element in the splitting field of the polynomial) is not in $K(ic)$. If we call $z$ a primitive cubic root of unity, we see that $z \cdot ic$ is also a root of $P(x)$, and we divide by the root $ic$ to conclude that $z$ is in the splitting field. But since $z = (-1 + \sqrt{-3})/2$, we conclude that $\sqrt{-3}$ is also in the splitting field. Now it remains to check that $\sqrt{-3}$ is not in $K(ic)$ to conclude the proof that this is not a Galois extension of $K$. Maybe there is a shorter way to check this, but here is one way: suppose $\sqrt{-3}$ belongs to $K(ic)$. Since $c$ also belongs to $K(ic)$, comparing degrees we deduce $K(ic) = K(\sqrt{-3} , c)$. We can also assume that this is a Galois extension of $K$, since we are arguing by contradiction and this is what we want to conclude. We now use the fact, noted by Jyrki, that $i$ belongs to $K(ic)$. This contradicts the previous equalities of fields, because it gives too many quadratic fields inside the field $K(\sqrt{-3}, c)$. This is (by our assumption) a Galois extension of $K$, of degree 6 and given by a minimal polynomial with coefficients in $Q$, so it is Galois over $Q$ of degree $6$ or $12$ and because it is obtained as the compositum of $K$ and the splitting field of $P(x)$ as a polynomial over $Q$, its Galois group contains the quadratic fields $K$, $Q(\sqrt{-3})$, and also of course $Q(\sqrt{-6})$. Here we have used again that $\sqrt{-3}$ is in our field. In particular the degree over $Q$ must be $12$, it can not be $6$. Observe that there is no room for more quadratic fields (inside a Galois field of degree 12 containing already 3 quadratic fields) so $i$ is not in our field, and this gives the contradiction we wanted.
Some help in giving a shorter proof that $\sqrt{-3}$ can not be contained in $K(ic)$? In any case, we conclude that the extension is not Galois.